# Is there a name for this "stack" of graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definitions

Let $G_1,\ldots,G_m$ be a sequence of graphs, all having the same number $n$ of vertices. For each pair $(G_i, G_{i+1})$ we add $n$ edges that connect the vertices of $G_i$ and $G_{i+1}$ bijectively. My question: Is there an established name for this "stack" of graphs?

Comment: given @Rob Pratt's comment about this being the cartesian product whenever all the $G_i$ are equal, I wonder what the categorical formalisation of what you describe is? some sort of fibred product? I don't know

Answer (score 3):

On page 4 of [1 ] , you find:

> [...] a *multiplex network* can be represented as a collection of graphs
>   $$\mathcal{G}=\{G^{(\ell)}=(V_n,E^{(\ell)})\}_{\ell \in V_L}$$
>   where $V_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is the set of nodes, $V_l=\{1,\ldots,L\}$ s the set of layers and $E^{(\ell)}\subset V_n\times V_n$ is the set of edges on layer $\ell$.

These structures are also sometimes called *multi-layer graphs*. Note that in the above formulation it is assumed that the nodes on each layer are the same (this models the bijective edges you are referring to).

[1 ] *Node and layer eigenvector centralities for multiplex networks.*
F Tudisco, F Arrigo, A Gautier - SIAM Journal on Applied Mathematics, 2018
([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08448.pdf))

Comment: There is a full [book on networks by Mark Newman](https://www.amazon.com/Networks-Introduction-Mark-Newman/dp/0199206651)

Answer (score 3):

In the case that you only have two graphs, and they are the same, say $G$, then the edges between the two copies of $G$ can be described by a permutation, and your graphs are precisely the *permutation graphs* defined by Chartrand and Harary in their 1967 paper "[Planar permutation graphs](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIHPB_1967__3_4_433_0/)" [Ann. Inst. H. Poincaré Sect. B (N.S.), **3**, pp. 433–438]. A cute example of such a "permutation graph" is the Petersen graph, which we can obtain with $G=C_5$.

(I cannot stress strongly enough that this is *not* the standard notion of [permutation graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_graph)!)

Answer (score 0):

In the special case that $G_i=G$ for all $i$, this is the *Cartesian product* of $G$ with the path on $n$ nodes.

Comment: That's not true if the vertices are simply connected "bijectively", as the question specifies.

Comment: Yes, for the Cartesian product the bijection is the identity, not an arbitrary bijection.